# Can I use Alfa long distance Wi-Fi with AppleTV AirPlay?

Tags: wifi, airplay

I'm told by Apple Support I cannot use my MacBook with OS X 10.9.3 with AppleTV AirPlay, so will be using it with just my Samsung TV and a 2nd TV (not a Smart TV Though,) for a family member who is living downstairs he has early lung cancer, & is just discovering computer world, and is in love with YouTube, so I am upstairs with a NetComm modem (TPG) and am thinking of getting a  Alfa long distance Wi-Fi. Is this OK, please?

Comment: give us more details, who said Airplay does not work on your MacBook? what Samsung TV, are you trying to use the Samsung TV as second monitor. What is the purpose of the Alfa long distance WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

The Alfa WiFi signal booster will work with many WiFi radios, if it is the right model and has the right driver for your OS.

If you are going to need the WiFi signal booster Antenna (Alfa long distance) will depend on your location.

Your Alfa antenna has to come with OS X drivers like this model:

http://www.crucialwifi.co.uk/Alfa_Network_AWUS036NHR_V2_bgn_LongRange_USB_Adapter_rtl8188ru/p740998_3940899.aspx

Normally a "well placed" wifi extender/repeater would be enough to bring your wifi signal to the floor below you. I have [Netgear N300](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN3000RP.aspx) for my wifi network around the home. Just plug it in wall socket in the stairwell somewhere. You need to know that the wifi speed will be cut in half, but still will be enough for Videos streaming from youtube etc.. if your original is strong.

Comment: thanks buscari am still very new to this, i wanted to tell you that you where so right i purchased a Netgear N300, and am trying to install it. ill get there eventually i suppose.